# Salesforce Active Directory Integration

Tags: activedirectory

Can you please confirm that in order to get our Active Directory users (and profiles/roles) synchronized with Salesforce, we need to get Salesforce Identity licences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the [Identity Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identityconnect_about.htm&type=5) product:

> Identity Connect integrates Microsoft Active Directory (AD) with
>   Salesforce. User information entered in AD is shared with Salesforce
>   seamlessly and instantaneously. Companies that use AD for user
>   management can use Identity Connect to manage Salesforce accounts.
>
> Changes in AD are reflected in Salesforce in near real time. For
>   example, when a user is created in AD, the Salesforce user account is
>   created as part of the provisioning process. When deprovisioned, the
>   user’s Salesforce session is revoked immediately.
>
> You can also use Identity Connect for single sign-on to Salesforce

Identity Connect is an add-on license available for Salesforce users on most Salesforce products. Add-on means that you have to purchase a user license (which can be an External or Internal Identity) and then buy Identity Connect on top of that. There might be product bundles that are referred to as "Identity" and these bundles might include both user licenses and Identity Connect. Talk to your account executive, these are questions they can answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. One more question. Are there any other alternatives to Integrate AD with Salesforce without using Identity Connect?